# OData connector to hit an endpoint failing intermittently even for small dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory, odata

have a Linked Service that uses OData connector to hit an endpoint and receive response back.
The endpoints are always up and running (I verify always through postman) but the LS fails frequently with below error.Even if I try from data bricks its sucessful.

The data is only around 50 rows and its intermittent. Even subsequent retries is not helping.log at service side is not helping much.

Error message:

Operation on target Copy to STG failed: ErrorCode=ODataFailedClientCreation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to create odata connection to RequestUrl.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A task was canceled.,Source=mscorlib,'